# My Z80 is not reading from memory (RD pin high and Databus is showing 00)

Tags: breadboard, z80, read

I am trying to run a simple program on my [AT28C256-15PU](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MPD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/AT28C256-Industrial-Grade-256-Kbit-Paged-Parallel-EEPROM-Data-Sheet-DS20006386.pdf) with a Z80 from [here](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/352873342855?hash=item5228e3e787:g:XT4AAOSwZH1d4qrl&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAA0HkrKhI3KL%2F9G%2FuZBNUYX0gOTF5JQbuMD0YCh%2BbcsYecO5DP04CbUmQXVyg9rX6Ip1CciyMs8dUE%2FhXHH2%2F4EnZCFR4IN%2FIBvgnz4lighmZ37cuNcaB%2BM030SWh3FKf5ayYt35smceaVM2wSgZRUmMfSV%2FPmAUsZ90ML516LgPBPjZ39MVzLhpDtamzwtf5SPBoPQAtePkDNQfzBOkzvkp8QvA8tTBdriJgvdyKfA%2BIDkR3Fi6AM%2FKi4SRMXCYHVLdCTKEOd4JqlFoC9RnibSx0%3D%7Ctkp%3ABFBM_LmrzYxj) I bought in mid 2023; it goes:

```
00:3E 
01:69   load $69 into a register
02:D3  
03:23   output A register on port address $23
04:C3 
05:00   jmp to $00
```

̷T̷h̷e̷ ̷b̷e̷h̷a̷v̷i̷o̷r̷ ̷o̷f̷ ̷t̷h̷e̷ ̷Z̷8̷0̷ ̷d̷o̷e̷s̷n̷'̷t̷ ̷a̷d̷d̷ ̷u̷p̷ ̷t̷o̷ ̷w̷h̷a̷t̷ ̷i̷s̷ ̷p̷r̷o̷g̷r̷a̷m̷m̷e̷d̷ ̷a̷s̷ ̷i̷t̷ ̷s̷i̷m̷p̷l̷y̷ ̷h̷a̷s̷ ̷M̷R̷E̷Q̷ ̷l̷o̷w̷ ̷b̷u̷t̷ ̷A̷1̷5̷ ̷a̷n̷d̷ ̷A̷1̷4̷ ̷a̷r̷e̷ ̷f̷l̷i̷c̷k̷e̷r̷i̷n̷g̷ ̷a̷n̷d̷ ̷R̷D̷ ̷i̷s̷ ̷h̷i̷g̷h̷.̷ ̷T̷h̷e̷ ̷d̷a̷t̷a̷ ̷l̷i̷n̷e̷s̷ ̷a̷r̷e̷ ̷a̷l̷s̷o̷ ̷o̷u̷t̷p̷u̷t̷t̷i̷n̷g̷ ̷$̷0̷0̷ ̷w̷h̷i̷c̷h̷ ̷i̷s̷ ̷n̷o̷t̷ ̷t̷h̷e̷ ̷$̷6̷9̷ ̷I̷ ̷p̷r̷o̷g̷r̷a̷m̷m̷e̷d̷ ̷i̷t̷ ̷t̷o̷ ̷o̷u̷t̷p̷u̷t̷.̷

[image: The newer schematic]

I connected /Wait,/BUSREQ,/INT, and /NMI to high. I connected RD to /OE on the AT28C256-15PU and/MREQ and A15 to a 74HC00N NAND gate to the /CE pin. I wired /WE to high (on that ROM) too. The reset behavior is routine and I bought a 4 MHz crystal from Farnell UK so it should be fine.

The behavior after reset is:WR is high, MREQ is low but IORQ is high, M1 is low, BUSREQ and HALT are high

Here are some photos of the physical thing:

also I now put the clock and reset module on to a new breadboard as well as updating my design to not use a 74HC00 as that was wrong memory mapping and doesn't work.The behavior also changed because now its read pin is low/active but it gets 1E from the address 0000 somehow with M1 also now being low/active

[image: new setup][image: another angle][image: yet another one]

Comment: That's a nightmare to debug. Oh well. No crystal should be connected like that. Is it really a crystal, or an oscillator module? You have got zero bypass caps there. Or if you do, I can't see them.

Comment: I ask because in your last question the problem was that the component you bought came from an unknown ebay seller. From where does the Z80 come? How sure it's what it says on top?

Comment: You haven't provided a proper schematic for us to help you. Please draw a proper schematic with pins labels and post it here.

Comment: Just as a start: You put /RESET to low, unless you press the reset button. So what do you expect the Z80 to do? Second, there are no decoupling capacitors for the supply. Third, you cannot wire LEDs directly on the Z80's pins. They need current limiting resistors. -- You urgently need to [edit] your question and provide a clean schematic.

Comment: The new schematic is a big improvement ... but still has issues. 1. From A8 on there is a mess. They all look shorted at the memory. 2. Your /RESET line connections are not correct. You need to pull up (to VCC) the line with a resistor and the switch should ground it. 3. Remove all LEDs from the address, data and control lines. They load them up and interfere with the signals.

Comment: BTW you don't need to connect wires from everywhere to a single GND and V+ symbol. Just add more symbols and avoid all the extra wires.

Answer (score 2):

OK, there's two options here:

1. your schematic is correct, but the implementation (loose contacts in breadboard, parasitic inductance through a million jumper wires, parasitic capacitance between breadboard rows, counterfeit components, …) makes it impossible to work
2. your schematic is wrong, making it impossible to work

We sadly can't read your schematic; you've supplied us with "colorful knotted rubber band" nest instead. That would be suboptimal for a circuit with one transistor, two resistors and an LED, but it simply isn't a method that allows you to communicate your schematic to us (and I even doubt it allows you to correctly plan your schematic from the beginning)! There are canonical standards how schematics look, and you've seen such on places like this and on retrocomputing forums, and you know yours doesn't look as clean as these!

And that's a real problem. This is confusing – so your chances of accidentally swapping two connections are *super* high.

So, honestly, you'll have to do two things:

1. Use a proper schematic editor, not a graphical toy program. Nobody can read what you produced there (and I think you wouldn't even disagree, if you take a step back)!
    There's a good reason that *schematic of a circuit* and *layout of a circuit* are two different things. The first allows you to reason and talk about the functionality, the second allows you implementing the circuit *after* the correctness has been "shown" with the schematic. A popular, because free and cross-platform, tool is KiCAD.
2. Having used that schematic editor to capture the schematic, let go of the idea of solderless breadboard. It's just too high a chance that one of your ca 60 wires (and thus, > 160 connections!) is unreliable.
   The math is simple: Assume that every single connection in itself is faulty with a probability of \$p_f\$. That makes the probability the connection is reliable \$(1-p_f)\$, and the probability that *all* \$N\$ connections are reliable then \$(1-p_f)^N\$. Say, you expect one in 250 connections to be faulty (that's very optimistic), so \$p_f=0.004\$, and you have \$N=160\$ connections: \$P_{\text{all reliable}} = (1-0.004)^{160} \approx 53\,\%\$. So you barely have a chance of half/half that your circuit works even if all your schematic is correct when basing it on this kind of breadboard! 
   That's simply not worth the time searching the flaky connection. Put your ICs, oscillator and all components that need to be close (decoupling caps!!) to them on a *soldered* proto-board, probably of the stripboard variant (you can use sockets). Solder these down. You can still add a pin header to connect them to the solderless breadboard for low speed stuff (like your LEDs).

If you're lazy, you'd not even go the protoboard route: You can use KiCAD (and other programs) to route your layout and then order it made for you – that's less than 5€ from china. You need to wait for the parcel to arrive, yes, but for 5€ you don't need to check every connection being 1. correctly plugged and 2. reliable. That makes sense for complex circuits like yours, in my humble opinion.

---

Talking about the schematic you show:

- you need to redo this. I don't see any decoupling caps, and this is a microcontroller running at MHzes. You need these, probably not only on the supply of the microcontroller, but also on your other IC and on the supply of the oscillator, as well.
- There's no series resistors on your LEDs, which means you rely on the limited output current capability of your IO pins to limit the current through the LED. In other words, you're risking damage to the microcontroller.
- What does a 330 Ω resistor in parallel with an LED, but in series with a switch, do? That seems put together without real thought. Here, you're literally shorting an LED between 5V and ground, with no current limitation. This will either burn your LED, or pull down your supply until nothing works, but most likely both at the same time.

  Back to basics: before using LEDs, you will have to understand a few basics about them. Wikipedia is your friend there!

Again, it's *important* to first design a schematic that shows which things are *logically* connected. In that schematic, the pins of the MCU don't have to be ordered like they are in real life. But the connections must be correct! Then, check that schematic design for mistakes. Did you miss anything? Do all LEDs have series resistors? Are they polarized the right way? Do you have a decoupling capacitor for each IC? Is the oscillator connected to the correct ("named") pin (instead of to the right pin number, humans tend to miscount)?

If yes, ask someone to look over your schematic. They will have feedback. Incorporate that feedback, and try to understand every single point!

Then, when that's done, you can start layouting your actual connections. On your drawing area, place the ICs like you want them to relate, add the decoupling caps, finally the LEDs in the places you want, their series resistors next to them. And after (and only *AFTER*) that you then create the highest speed connections, then the lower speed, then the power and ground connections. Your schematic editor and layouting program knows about the connections you need to make from the schematic, so it can show you what needs to be connected – so you *can't* make mistakes.

Then you have something physically producible, which is probably correct and stands a fair chance of working. Ask someone for a review! Be prepared to delete the whole layout and do it again; this is normal after getting feedback. You get smarter, very quickly, I promise!